# How come I can't use the length number from this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created an array, and when I try to get the length of the array it works fine.

```
var map = [
  [3, 0, 0, 2],
  [7, 6, 6, 8],
  [7, 6, 6, 8],
  [5, 1, 1, 4]
];

var i = map.length;
```

`i` outputs `4`.

When I try to use the `i` variable to get the column using `var j = map[i].length;` the console returns "`map[i]` is undefined". How come this won't work, but replacing `i` with an actual number works?

Here is an [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk7f8Ls2/1/), just uncomment line 11.

Comment: You mean: `map[map.length - 1].length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is equal to 4, as you said. JS array indices start from 0, so the last element in your array is `map[3]` which means there is no element at `map[4]`

You need to do `map[i-1]` - this code should work:

```
var j = map[i-1].length;
```

And here is it working in your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zk7f8Ls2/2/

Comment: No problem at all! It's an easy thing to miss!

Answer (score 2):

Because table index are [zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). The table length is 4 but indexes are 0, 1, 2 and 3. When you try to access index 4, you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `i` is 4, and remember that arrays start with `0` if you want to see the last item of the array just add -1 `map[i-1]`